# Error in Serverless Deploy with basic API HTTP - Rest template on AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a issue when I do `serverless deploy` in command line with a pre-built Serverless Framework in AWS CLI for Node.Js HTTP API Rest application.

```
Deploying aws-node-http-api-project to stage dev (us-east-1)
Warning: Not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction for at least one of the lambda functions. Deployment will not be skipped even if service files did not change.

× Stack aws-node-http-api-project-dev failed to deploy (80s)
Environment: win32, node 18.16.0, framework 3.30.1, plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
CREATE_FAILED: ApiLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Service returned error code AccessDeniedException (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: cd3c14a3-fe9d-415e-9f7a-ddb068b98381)" (RequestToken: e76b2b77-7da2-1229-6e7d-b24073a52979, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

View the full error: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A801094063366%3Astack%2Faws-node-http-api-project-dev%2Fc7530480-eb49-11ed-917c-127532f63075
```

[CloudFormation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqtpL.png)
Can someone help me? I don't know what else I can do to fix this problem...

I created a user with Administrator access + Lambda:GetFunction, and programatic access key (which is configured in AWS CLI console) and the problem continues.

AdministratorAccess JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

LambdaGetFunction(custom) JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:GetFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you configure the AWS credentials using the default profile?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, I did, speaking with AWS support, they said it's possible the function is not working because they think my account has been compromised. I'm talking to them now via site and I'll update.

Comment: So I talked to them and they put restriction on accounts once you change IP Address, machine or something like that, they didn't give me a real explanation. 

So for everyone facing this problem, you have to contact support, specify that you are not being allowed to do functions on root account, and they will ask you several questions and eventually unlock your account back to you.

I hope this helps.